# Perform long-running operation inside onNewToken() method for FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with Firebase Messaging Service on Android. For that I've created my own Android Service that extends from `FirebaseMessagingService` as stated in the documentation.

```
class MyCustomMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    ... More core here
    
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        // Long running operation
        GlobalScope.launch { repository.saveNewToken(token) }
    }
    ... More code here
}
```

The thing is that I need to call a suspendable function when a new token arrives inside `onNewToken(token)` in order to save the token.

Right now I'm using `GlobalScope` because I want the token to be saved even if the `Service` terminates. Previously I was using a new coroutine scope tied to the `lifecycle` of the `Service` but I thought that maybe `onDestroy()` could be called before the token was saved.

Also tried to use `runBlocking { repository.saveNewToken(token) }` because `onNewToken()` is supposed to be called from a worker thread. Another option that comes to my mind is to use a `Worker` with a one time request but this option seems kind of overkill.

What do you guys think is the most proper way to call a suspendable function from inside `onNewToken()` guaranteeing that the `Job` is not canceled even if the `Service` is terminated and the resources are used properly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to point that if the `Job` is cancelled, it doesn't mean that the launched code won't complete. It depends on suspend function implementation. If your `saveNewToken` doesn't check for `job.isActive` or doesn't call `ensureActive` or doesn't call any suspend function, it won't stop running and everything will finish fine.

If so, you can continue using `lifecycle`-aware scope safely, and since `Service` has a lifecycle I'd say that that looks like intended usage.

`GlobalScope` [intended usage](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) is for top-level background processes, that should never die unless app process is finished. Ofc, worst case scenario you will finish with several running coroutines that are considered active.

Next step is to look at your `saveNewToken` again. Usually you will call suspend functions there, and if `Job` is cancelled they'll throw CancellationException. If you want to ensure that something will be saved anyway, you can use this neat thing: `withContext(NonCancellable)`, [see here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block). Just use it with care so you won't end up with infinite hanging loops using up resources (:

**tldr;**
Service's lifecycle-aware `CoroutineScope` + `withContext(NonCancellable)` where you really need it.

Comment: Thank you! Got caught on another thing but will check this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way to call a **suspendable** function from inside onNewToken() guaranteeing that the **Job** is not canceled even if the Service is terminated and the resources are used properly is to use a Job with a **CoroutineScope** that is tied to the lifecycle of the Service.

```
class MyCustomMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main)

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        // Long running operation
        scope.launch {
            repository.saveNewToken(token)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        scope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but let's suppose that `repository.saveNewToken(token)` takes much time to get executed, isn't it possible for the Service to be destroyed before the action is even completed?

Comment: If the Service is destroyed while the coroutine is running, the coroutine will be canceled and the repository.saveNewToken(token) function will not be completed.
To avoid this problem, you can use a Job with a timeout(). A timeout() will cancel the Job after a certain amount of time, even if the Job is still running.